# Error exporting from org-mode to beamer

Tags: beamer, emacs, org-mode, export

When trying to export from org to beamer I get this msg:

> Processing LaTeX file ./ppt.tex...
>   org-latex-compile: PDF file ./ppt.pdf wasn't produced: [undefined control sequence]

I don't know what that means. Can someone please help me understand and fix this error? Perhaps I haven't properly configured **emacs** for this kind of export?

This is part of my `.emacs` file which I copied from one of the questions here in TeX.SX. I'm not sure if I have AUCTeX configured with `shell-escape` but I'd like to have the proper code in my `.emacs` file for when it's time to include some python lines in the final pdf, be it an article or a beamer presentation.

```lisp
    ;; Org mode and bearmer export
(require 'ox-beamer)
(setq org-latex-to-pdf-process 
  '("pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
"pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
"pdflatex --shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))


(defun my-beamer-bold (contents backend info)
 (when (eq backend 'beamer)
  (replace-regexp-in-string "\\`\\\\[A-Za-z0-9]+" "\\\\textbf" contents)))

(add-to-list 'org-export-filter-bold-functions 'my-beamer-bold)

(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(org-babel-do-load-languages
 'org-babel-load-languages
 '((python . t)
  (latex . t)))
(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate nil)
(setq org-babel-python-command "ipython --pylab --pdb --nosep --classic --no-banner --no-confirm-exit")

(setq org-latex-listings 'minted)
(setq org-latex-minted-options
   '(("fontsize" "\\footnotesize")("bgcolor" "black")("obeytabs" "true")))

(require 'ox-latex)
(setq org-src-fontify-natively t)
(setq org-latex-pdf-process
   '("pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"
    "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o   %f"
    "pdflatex -shell-escape -interaction nonstopmode -output-directory %o %f"))
(setq org-src-preserve-indentation t)
```

*The following is the `ppt.org` file which I can't translate into pdf!*

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation, smaller]
#+BEAMER_THEME: CambridgeUS
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+OPTIONS: H:3 email:n |:t
#+TITLE: CNT antennas
#+AUTHOR: W.W.
#+DATE: Dec 2015

* What are CNTs?
** who, what, when, how

* How do antennas work?
** /what/, when, how
 - a short description of a simple antenn
 - what parameters define the quality of an antenna
 - what are the common use of an antenna

* How can CNTs be used as antennas? 
 - how does it work?
   + describe the advantages...
   + ...and the disadvantages
 - any alternative materials?

* Other applications of CNTs to communications
 - self-assembly
see ch.4 of S.F. Bush "Nanoscale Communication Networks"
```

Comment: Which command are you using to transform your .org into pdf? Is it `org-latex-to-pdf-process`?

Comment: Isn't it `C-c C-e l` and then choose either `P` or `O`? How do I set it? From the **Org** menu of emacs while `ppt.org` is open?

Comment: I don' t have python installed in my system (Windows 7 32 bit) or any other related package from elpa. Does that account for the error? I'd also like to recant my previous request -- doesn't matter if I have to pull out the python/minted lines, what is the **bare minimum** `.emacs` configuration to get org-mode to properly translate into a pdf/beamer presentation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've add the code you provide to my emacs setup (could be found on my github sorry for the publicity) with emacs 24.4.1 .

The error come from the sentance `/what/, when, how`. Beamer don't really enjoy using `\emph{}` and other command that are used in section title. A way to avoid it is to use LaTeX command for this point: `** \protect\emph{what}, when, how`.

Which give as a result:

```
#+LaTeX_CLASS: beamer
#+LaTeX_CLASS_OPTIONS: [presentation, smaller]
#+BEAMER_THEME: CambridgeUS
#+BEAMER_FRAME_LEVEL: 2
#+OPTIONS: H:3 email:n |:t
#+TITLE: CNT antennas
#+AUTHOR: W.W.
#+DATE: Dec 2015

* What are CNTs?
** who, what, when, how

* How do antennas work?
** \protect\emph{what}, when, how
 - a short description of a simple antenn
 - what parameters define the quality of an antenna
 - what are the common use of an antenna

* How can CNTs be used as antennas? 
 - how does it work?
   + describe the advantages...
   + ...and the disadvantages
 - any alternative materials?

* Other applications of CNTs to communications
 - self-assembly
see ch.4 of S.F. Bush "Nanoscale Communication Networks"
```

I haven't found a solution at this point using only org command if someone have it, I'm interested.